# Unexpected clock results

Tags: c++

I am converting a .net program to C++. While the program runs correctly, it is much slower than the .net version (2 minutes vs. 18 hours!!!). To look for inefficient code, I placed a few timers in the key functions, but the results are not what I expected.

Looking at the highest level timer, if I write it like this...

```
auto TotalTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
double TotalDuration;

do
{
    TotalTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    RunPrimaryFunction(); // Runs the 
    TotalDuration += std::chrono::duration<double>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - TotalTime).count();

    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Function 1 Time: " << Function1Duration << "%\n";
    std::cout << "Function 2 Time: " << Function2Duration << "%\n";
    std::cout << "Function 3 Time: " << Function3Duration << "%\n";
    std::cout << "Function 4 Time: " << Function4Duration << "%\n";
    std::cout << "Function 5 Time: " << Function5Duration << "%\n";
    std::cout << "Total: " << TotalDuration << "\n";
    
} while (!Done);
```

The time for TotalDuration is visibly slow. It increases by about 0.1 seconds for every second the program runs.

If I make a change to this...

```
auto TotalTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
double TotalDuration;

do
{
    TotalTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    RunPrimaryFunction(); // Runs the 

    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Function 1 Time: " << Function1Duration << "%\n";
    std::cout << "Function 2 Time: " << Function2Duration << "%\n";
    std::cout << "Function 3 Time: " << Function3Duration << "%\n";
    std::cout << "Function 4 Time: " << Function4Duration << "%\n";
    std::cout << "Function 5 Time: " << Function5Duration << "%\n";
    TotalDuration += std::chrono::duration<double>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - TotalTime).count();
    std::cout << "Total: " << TotalDuration << "\n";
    
} while (!Done);
```

The time for TotalDuration appears to be increasing at 1 second for every second as I would expect.

This would suggest that the clear screen and outputs of the other function timers is extremely slow, which is untrue as the overall program execution time is unchanged with the removal of these lines.

Comment: Instead of inserting your own timing code, you should use a profiler application.

Comment: How big is the source for the actual program? You're posting your timing code but not the converted C code. There may be some issues that would cause a slowdown. It might be helpful to post the `.net` version and the C version to ensure they're equivalent and the C version is optimal. If short on space, the full C version would be preferable. Are you compiling with `-Wall -Wextra`? The posted snippet implies that `TotalDuration` is uninitialized and if it's function scoped, this is UB (undefined behavior).

Comment: I suspect what you're seeing is some effects of the buffering of `std::cout`.

Comment: `double TotalDuration;` -- what do you believe the value of `TotalDuration` is now, to which `TotalDuration += ....` updates later?

Comment: How are you compiling the C++ code? Without optimizations would be my initial guess ... Also, output to console is very slow (relatively speaking).

Comment: All, that you for your help. I don’t have time to address every comment right now, but you all made me double check and search new paths which eventually led me to the underlying issue. I appreciate you taking time to help the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further review, it appears that the line system("cls"); is the culprit taking about 90% of the time of the loop.